# Channel.updateOverwrite not a function

Tags: javascript, discord.js

This creates the channel as i want it to but it doesnt post the message "thank you for contacting support" in the new channel.

message.channel.send sends it to the channel that !ticket was put (not the new one which i dont want)
channel.send and channel.updateOverwrite comes back as not a function. i cant seem to find the error!

this is a basic ticket bot.

```
module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
 let channel = message.guild.channels.create(`ticket: ${message.author.tag}`,{type: 'text'}).then(channel =>{
 channel.setParent('868513748711800853')
 });
   

  channel.updateOverwrite(message.guild.id, {
    SEND_MESSAGE: false,
    VIEW_CHANNEL: false,
  }); 
  channel.updateOverwrite(message.author, {
    SEND_MESSAGE: true,
    VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
  });
  const reactionMessage = channel.send("Thank you for contacting support!");

  try {
    reactionMessage.react("");
    reactionMessage.react("⛔");
  } catch (err) {
    channel.reply("Error sending emojis!");
    throw err;
  }

  const collector = reactionMessage.createReactionCollector(
    (reaction, user) => message.guild.members.cache.find((member) => member.id === user.id).hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR"),
    { dispose: true }
  );

  collector.on("collect", (reaction, user) => {
    switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
      case "":
        channel.updateOverwrite(message.author, { SEND_MESSAGES: false });
        break;
      case "⛔":
        channel.send("Deleting this channel in 5 seconds!");
        setTimeout(() => message.channel.delete(), 5000);
        break;
    }
  });

  message.channel
    .send(`We will be right with you! ${channel}`)
    .then((msg) => {
      setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 7000);
      setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 3000);
    }).catch((err) => {
      throw err;
   });
  
};

module.exports.help = {
   name: "ticket",
   aliases: [""] 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`channels.create()` returns a pending promise so you'll need for it to be resolved. As `channel` is a promise, when you call `channel.updateOverwrite()` and `channel.send()`, it doesn't have these methods, they are undefined, so it will throw an error.

```js
let channel = await message.guild.channels.create(
  `ticket: ${message.author.tag}`,
  { type: 'text' },
);

await channel.setParent('868513748711800853');

channel.updateOverwrite(message.guild.id, {
  SEND_MESSAGE: false,
  VIEW_CHANNEL: false,
});
channel.updateOverwrite(message.author, {
  SEND_MESSAGE: true,
  VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
});
```